# View JSF page structure

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea

I'm working on project which uses JSF as UI framwork.
There is a lot of huge forms which contains many `<ui:include>` tags referring to other part of pages and they also includes others etc. When you drilling into structure it's really headache to hold it in your head.
So, my question is there any feature in IntelliJ Idea (or maybe in other IDE) which may graphically show such hierarchy?
Thanks for advice

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: The tags you added are too broad/unrelated. I removed them

Comment: I'm using NetBeans. What I do is press the Ctrl key which allows me to click the ui:include src attribute to jump to that file.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Idea works the same. But i'd like to see somthing like class hierarchy, but for includes in jsf pages.